# Form Processing PHP in HTML page?

Tags: php, forms

I am re-designing a site for my client. They have a PHP-based Contact Us form called `contact-us.php`.

I am somewhat familiar with PHP, but not an expert by any means. The form would basically post the fields, verify validity, build and email, and send. Give a confirmation if no errors on a `thankyou.php` page.

In the new design, I am working with HTML5 and CSS3, trying to expand my knowledge base.

The customer wants the Contact Us form on every page, as a "right nav" sidebar.

Currently all pages are `.html`. Does this now require that I change all pages to `.php` to properly process the Contact Us form?

The sidebar that contains the Contact Us form is just a basic include file right now..

Figured I better solve this now before its too far down the road and causes more work.

thoughts? ideas? Am I just stuck developing the site using .php file extensions for all pages?

Comment: Any page that is going to do server-side processing needs to be .php rather than .html. If its just a static html page you can leave it as .html, in other words.

Comment: If there is no PHP being processed on any page, you don't need to change all `.html` to `.php`. Only what's being used to process `mail()`. However, you can if you want to; it won't make much of a difference, just as long as the code's good.

Comment: just add the html form stuff on every page - and post it to php using ajax/javascript/jquery

Comment: Not sure who down voted my Q, but whatever. Thanks all.. I think I have my answer.

Comment: You're welcome Tony.

Comment: Another option Tony, is using Ajax to process the PHP/mail inside your contact page and that can be `.html`, no problem. Only what's processed for `mail()` needs a `.php` extension. Here's are a few links http://www.sanwebe.com/2011/12/making-simple-jquery-ajax-contact-form and http://teachingyou.net/php/simple-php-contact-form-using-ajax/ - You can keep Googling using "ajax php mail" for keywords.

Comment: @Fred-ii- that's just what i said in my comment...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would have to change  the extension from `.html` to `.php` if you are going to include a `contact form` in sidebar of every page.

Changing to `.php` extension wouldn't make any difference in functioning of your HTML code, it would just enable you to `POST` your form data for processing...So go ahead..

To do with AJAX..
`index.html`

```
     <form id="upload" action="" method="post">
                Name:<input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br><br>
                Email:<input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" />
                </div>
     </form>
<div id="message"></div>
```

For your ajax.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#upload").on('submit',(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "upload.php", // Url to which the request is send
                type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
                data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
                contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
                cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
                processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
                success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
                { 
                    $('#message').html = "success";
                }
            });
        }));
    });
```

And for your `upload.php` file:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
//etc depending upon your form inputs. You can store this in your database.
?>
```

Anything you echo in PHP can be obtained in `success:function(data)` in `js` file.

For HTML files you will just have to include the `ajax.js` in you `script tag`.

Comment: no, he doesn't need to. he just can make use of some ajax.

Comment: You can use AJAX anytime for asynchronously submitting your form. But tony was curious to know about form submission using only PHP. If he has the choice it it always better to go with  AJAX.

Comment: he never said that he is only able to use PHP.

Comment: there was no reference so I assumed it was PHP only.. :P AJAX is always welcomed for form submission..

Comment: That was kind of my question... and can see why I would have gotten down voted.. I was trying to see if I "had" to convert .html pages to .php in order to still keep the Contact Us form on every page. I am not a big AJAX developer, so the logical flow of how that would work is a bit over my head... I think at this point, due to time constraints, converting the pages to .php files would be easiest.

Comment: For ajax, you will only need to create two files...one `.js` and one `.php`... `.js` will execute your ajax script and `.php` will process your form data. For rest of HTML pages you will just have to include your `.js` file in your script tag

Comment: @MoidMohd that's not true - you don't need a `.js` file, you can include your javascript right into the html file with `<script></script>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

For future purpose of the form, it is better you change all the pages to .php since you want the contact us form on every page.

Go to the right nav sidebar where you want the form to appear and insert the following code

```
<?php 
require_once "right-nav.php";
?>
```

Insert this on every page where you want the form to appear, you need to save the page with a .php extension

In the right-nav.php file, put the source code for displaying the form

In future when you want to make changes to the form, you will only work on the right-nav.php file